# PyDev Eclipse Installed Not Showing In Preferences Latest Java

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Freshly installed Windows 10 and everything  (literally today)
Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639

java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)

PyDev 9.2.0

Ultimate goal: to have Eclipse configured to use with multiple languages.
Installed: Eclipse for C/C++
Trying to get python on it. Failing.
I understand next to nothing in how ide or toolchain works. I'm much better at writing code than configuring IDE, compilers and other stuff (yet).

My actions: installed Eclipse. Followed the guide about how to install PyDev via Eclipse itself "Help->Install New Software". Did it, no errors. In "Window->Preferences" no PyDev, no Python.
[PyDev install manual on PyDev.org](https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)

I went to google, it found several stackoverflow and other forums and/or articles about it. Read everything that looked at least remotely relevant. They talked about Java version required for Python. I installed the newest version of JDK (17). I edited eclipse.ini to include path to Java v17. Restarted Eclipse. It crashed on launch. I went to CMD and tried java -version. It gave me the wrong (old) version, so I edited System Variables (created JAVA_HOME and added bin to Path). Eclipse launched OK. No PyDev.

Also, multiple sources talked about different versions of PyDev to choose from. Strangely enough, I have only 1 version available in "Help->Install New Software" even if I uncheck "show only the latest version". There is still only 9.2.0 and nothing else.

Fine, I thought, I will install you with as "dropins" (whatever that is), according to the same manual from PyDev.org. Uninstalled PyDev via "Help->About Eclipse->Installation details" (overall I installed-uninstalled several times). Downloaded PyDev zip, unzipped it (two folders - "features" and "plugins"). Dragged those two folders into "dropins". PyDev not showing up.

As I said before, I understand very little in Eclipse and how to configure it, and there is nobody to ask. With my limited knowledge, I'm out of ideas now.

**EDIT** Added log
I think I found the log. Deleted it to remove all the stuff from the other day, launched Eclipse:

this is from Window->Show View->Other->General->Log
[image]

Full log file is a kilometer long.

```
!SESSION 2022-02-06 16:12:44.226 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.22.0.I20211124-1800
java.version=17.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2022-02-06 16:12:51.076
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1019)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.lambda$1(ModuleContainer.java:1834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1829)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1777)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1739)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:339)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\Eclipse IDE\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getSharedPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.lambda$2(BundleContextImpl.java:808)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:802)
    ... 13 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\Eclipse IDE\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getSharedPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.lambda$2(BundleContextImpl.java:808)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1019)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.lambda$1(ModuleContainer.java:1834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1829)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1777)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1739)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:339)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2022-02-06 16:13:06.666
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\user'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui 4 0 2022-02-06 16:13:16.623
!MESSAGE Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\Eclipse IDE\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\Eclipse IDE\eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getSharedPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getKnownRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Artifact.getKnownRepositories(CachingRepositoryManager.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core.P2Util.getKnownRepositories(P2Util.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.isNeeded(P2TaskImpl.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.initNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2282)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.performStartup(SetupUIPlugin.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin.access$5(SetupUIPlugin.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.SetupUIPlugin$1$1.run(SetupUIPlugin.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

**EDIT 2: Problem solved!**

1. I installed Python (duh!)
2. Put Eclipse into another folder.

Comment: Check the Error Log view for error messages, and add them to the question.

Comment: @nitind gladly! Just tell me how exactly or I'll add something wrong. What log specifically?

Comment: @nitind figured out how to get the log you probably mean. Added.

Comment: I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639236/registry-directory-not-available-c-program-files-eclipse-p2-org-eclipse-equino
My Eclipse is also in Program Files, because I thought it's a logical place for a program to be. I will reinstall to another place and report back

Comment: Try putting it somewhere other than under Program Files. File permissions are strange there.

Comment: Problem solved. 1) I installed Python (duh!) 2) Put Eclipse into another folder. Now I have PyDev in preferences! This was as dumb as it gets, but setting up developer tools is probably more difficult than programming itself urgh.